# How to refer to an object property from within a function that is also an object property in a service factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to call `getAllProducts` method in `addProduct` success callback but it is showing that `getAllProducts is not defined`

```
  'use strict';

ProductBuilder.factory('productBuilderService', function ($http, secKey, urlContent) {
    return {

        getAllProducts: function ($scope) {
            $http.get(urlContent + '/api/Products')
                    .success(function (response) {
                        $scope.products = response;
                    });
        },

        addProduct: function ($scope) {
            var data = {
                "action": "post",
                "product":
                    {
                        "ID": $scope.ID,
                        "Name": $scope.Name,
                        "Section": $scope.Section
                    }
            }

            $http({
                url: urlContent + '/api/Products',
                method: "POST",
                data: data
            }).success(function (response) {
                getAllProducts($scope);
            });
        },

        deleteProductByID: function (id, $scope) {
            var data = {
                "action": "delete",
                "rule":
                    {
                        "ID": id,
                        "Name": $scope.Name,
                        "Section": $scope.Section
                    }
            }

            $http({
                url: urlContent + '/api/Products',
                method: "POST",
                data: data
            }).success(function (response) {
                getAllProducts($scope);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Create a separate function

Comment: I want to use ``productBuilderService.AnyMethodName`` in controller so don't want to use separate function

Comment: Use ` this.getAllProducts($scope);`  in addProduct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getAllProducts` is a property of the object you're returning, not a local variable that you can call by itself. I recommend you create the object first, then return it. That way, you can reference the object it belongs to.

```
var myObj = {
  getAllProducts: function() { //etc
  anotherFunction: function() {
     //etc
     myObj.getAllProducts();

  }
};
return myObj;
```

Another option is to make the function first, then store it to the object:

```
function getAllProducts() { //etc } // local variable
return {
  getAllProducts: getAllProducts, // assign the local variable to the object
  anotherFunction: function() {
    getAllProducts(); // now you can call the local variable
  }
}
```

You can also use the `this` pointer from within an object to refer to other properties of that object, but I recommend avoiding the `this` pointer. The value of `this` changes depending on where and sometimes when you use it.

Assuming that the context (the value of `this`) has not been changed, then `this.getAllByProducts()` will refer to the property `getAllProducts` on the object you're returning if called from within one of the functions that are properties of that object. However, in the particular place that you're calling `getAllProducts`, the value of `this` is set by the `$http` call and no longer refers to your object. That means that you would have to cache the value of `this` to a variable while it refers to your object and use that variable:

```
return {
  getAllProducts: function() { //etc }
  anotherFunction: function() {
    var that = this;
    // later
    that.getAllProducts();
  }
};
```

Even with caching the `this` pointer, its value could still be changed at that point because the context of a function can be changed by methods like `bind, apply, and call`. The `this` pointer adds a lot of complexity and room for error. Two things programmers should hate. That's why I recommend the first approach I mentioned.

Comment: can you please elaborate, because I am already using ``productBuilderService.addProduct`` from my controller

Comment: @Gaurav123 right, because what you're returning is assigned to `productBuilderService`, but you don't have access to that inside of the factory itself. This is very basic JavaScript. It would be good for you to study about scopes, variables and object references.

Comment: Done....I have created new object var  getProducts= function ($scope) {
        $http.get(urlContent + '/api/Products')
                .success(function (response) {
                    $scope.products= response;
                });
    }

Comment: Then I called it as  ``getAllProducts: function ($scope) {
getProducts($scope);
        },``

rest remained the same and it works